# Creating directory on root doesn't work via npm but does running node directly

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

`app.js` (root is not file owner)

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.mkdirSync('/root/tmp');
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "app": "node app.js"
  }
}
```

When I run as root `npm run app` I got

```
> app
> node app.js

node:internal/fs/utils:344
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/tmp'
```

But it works when I run just `node app.js`. Which setting/option of `npm` can help me run `npm run app` without errors?

Why npm run change user? How to force npm not to change user?

Comment: That's interesting. I can confirm I see that same behavior on Linux if I'm running the terminal as a superuser. I know `npm` runs via `env` whereas when you run `node` you're calling it directly. But beyond that I don't know the details of why this is.

Comment: How did you open the terminal/shell where you're running these commands?

Comment: I run `xfce4-terminal` with `bash`. Then `su`.  Then I see `[...]# `.

Answer (score 2):

I can replicate the behavior you see on Linux if I run the commands in a shell I've run via `sudo`, like this: `sudo bash`. As in the question, `npm run app` fails but `node app.js` works.

The difference is that `npm run app` runs the executable JavaScript file `npm-cli.js` from the `npm` package, which looks like this:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('../lib/cli.js')(process)
```

That tells us it's running `node` via [`env`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html#env-invocation).

So I got to thinking: What user does that run as? So I added `"who": "whoami"` to `package.json` and did `npm run who`. The answer is: It runs as my normal account, **not** as `root`, even when I run that from a shell I've launched via `sudo bash`. My normal user account can't (of course) create subdirectories of `root`.

Comment: Why npm run change user? How to force npm not to change user?

Comment: @pank - The change is brought about by invoking the script via `env`. I don't know the ints and outs of `sudo` for why that reverts to the basic user. I don't think you can make `npm` not do that without writing a new wrapper for the CLI script, but someone else may know of a way.